# ¿Qué opción es correcta: "y e-mail" o "e e-mail"?

Tags: gramática, conjunciones

Estaba escribiendo la frase "nombre, apellido e e-mail" cuando me surgió la duda: ¿debo escribir **"e e-mail"** o **"y e-mail"**?

La "e" de "e-mail" suena como "i" (*i meil*), pero se escribe con "e". ¿A cuál de las dos le tengo que prestar atención?

---

Nótese que soy de Argentina, y acostumbramos (al menos en el grupo en el que me estoy comunicando) a incluir términos en inglés al hablar, con una pronunciación que *pretende* ser la del inglés. En particular, el término *e-mail* es pronunciado por todos como *imeil*, y jamás como *email*, como ocurre en algunas otras regiones/contextos.

Comment: Igual puedes evitarlo por completo si usas *correo* ;)

Comment: O solo "mail". Actualmente nadie pensará que "mail" significa correo regular por carta, menos en español

Comment: Siendo que _Nombre_ y _Apellido_ están en español, ¿por qué no dejar todo en español y escribir **Correo electrónico**?

Comment: La pregunta es sobre un texto que estaba escrito, no sobre cómo escribir uno. Particularmente con términos que están tan aceptados en la sociedad (varía de país en país, claro) no veo problema con mantenerlos tal y como están, tal como *e-mail* o *mouse*. No veo tan terrible adoptar palabras de otro idioma cuando resulta "conveniente". En el inglés también se hace con términos como *"RSVP"*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La Fundéu [dice al respecto](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/e-mail-tras-conjuncion-y-5634/):

> […] debe usarse la forma «e» de la conjunción copulativa «y», pues se supone que casi todos los hispanohablantes leen eso como «imeil».

Esto es coherente con lo [establecido](http://www.rae.es/consultas/cambio-de-la-y-copulativa-en-e) en la *Gramática* de las Academias:

> Si la palabra que sigue a la conjunción no es española y comienza por el sonido vocálico /i/, sigue vigente la regla, aunque por tratarse de una voz extranjera el sonido /i/ inicial no se escriba como *i* o *hi*:
>
> > Escriba su teléfono **e** *e-mail* (la *e* de *e-mail* se pronuncia [i] en inglés).

En resumen, el principio más importante tras la norma que regula las formas *y* y *e* es **fonético**, es decir, depende del sonido de las palabras más que de su grafía.

Pero en cualquier caso es mejor evitar el anglicismo innecesario y decir *correo*.

Comment: excelente respuesta +1

Answer (score 10):

Si el contexto de la frase contiene varias acepciones en otro/s idioma/s y se sobreentiende que el lector pronunciará dichas acepciones en su forma original sería correcto utilizar 'e', pero lo más común es "españolizar" los extranjerismos al pronunciar, y por tanto utilizar 'y' ya que pronunciaríamos *email* en lugar de *imeil*.

*E-mail* es una abreviatura de Electronic Mail (Address), que en español viene siendo (Dirección de) *Correo Electrónico*, por lo que una abreviatura muy común suele ser *correo-e*.

Comment: Gracias por abarcar ambos casos. Acabo de agregar algo de contexto a la pregunta: en Argentina, al menos con la gente con que me contacto, jamás escuché pronunciar _email_, si no que parece ser universal el uso de _imeil_.

Comment: Totalmente correcto!!!! Ocupar e-mail o imeil o email es simplemente un mal hábito. Por favor utilicemos cada vez más correo-e y correos-e al hablar y al escribir. Como bien dice @Blas Soriano, porque son dichas abreviaturas las correspondientes a correo electrónico y correos electrónicos.

Comment: Particularmente con términos que están tan aceptados en la sociedad (varía de país en país, claro) no veo problema con mantenerlos tal y como están, tal como *e-mail* o *mouse*. No veo tan terrible adoptar palabras de otro idioma cuando resulta "conveniente". En el inglés también se hace con términos como *"RSVP"*. Me parecería un espanto oír a alguien decir "correo-e".

Comment: La abreviatura calcada sería en español *correo e.*, con espacio y punto, pero sin guion.

Answer (score 4):

Mientras no olvides "e-mail" en cursivas, como debe ser, no se verá tan feo:

Nombre, apellido e *e-mail*.

Aunque se ve mas bonito: 
Tu nombre, tu apellido y tu *e-mail*.

Comment: Siendo que _Nombre_ y _Apellido_ están en español, ¿por qué no dejar todo en español y escribir **Correo electrónico**?

Comment: @DGaleano, por supuesto que es preferible dejar todo en español, pero esta respuesta abarca aquellos casos en que se quiere utilizar el anglicismo intencionadamente, y donde corresponden las cursivas.

Comment: @fitojb Me confundí. Creí que el foro era sobre el buen uso del español y por eso recomendé la opción correcta. Si intencionalmente se quieren mezclar idiomas entonces ahí si no hay reglas y cada uno puede hablar esperanto si quiere. _Just kidding ;-) !!_

Comment: @DGaleano Mi ŝatas poliglotoj! =)

Answer (score 1):

Yo creo que depende de si es hablando o escribiendo. Escribiendo "e e-mail" no tendría sentido para alguien que no sepa pronunciarlo. Y hablando, "y e-mail" también queda un poco raro, por lo que yo escribiría "y e-mail" y diría "e e-mail"