# Reemplazo de 'y' por 'e' previo a abreviatura

Tags: gramática, conjunciones

¿Hay que reemplazar la **y** por la **e** previo a abreviaturas que fonéticamente comienzan con e, pero cuya palabra no necesariamente lo es? Aquí les va un ejemplo:

> Enfermedades del tejido conectivo e Hipertensión Pulmonar
>
> Enfermedades del tejido e HP

Ya que solo se nombra en el texto hipertensión pulmonar (HP) una vez y luego sólo abreviado.

¡Gracias y muy buena la página!

Comment: No, porque tiene que tener el sonido vocal. En la abreviación se lee como *hache* y por tanto como no lleva el sonido *i*, no se sustituye la *y* por *e*.

Comment: Imagino que dependería de cómo el escritor imagina la pronunciación.  Si el lector lo pronunciará como «hachepé», se debe escribir *y*, pero si lo pronunciará como «hipertensión pulmonar» (a pesar de la grafía abreviada), se debe escribir *i*.

Comment: @guifa A eso voy, todo depende del sonido vocal.

Comment: Pregunta similar: [_¿Qué opción es correcta: “y e-mail” o “e e-mail”?_](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12866/12637)

Comment: @CarlosAlejo llegué aquí desde [¿“Toddler” en castellano?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17521/1674) buscando qué debo escribir, _y infant_ o _e infant_. ¿Te parece que abramos una pregunta más genérica preguntando por cómo hacerlo si se trata de palabras extranjeras? Parece que el tema puede ser de utilidad. O también podemos ofrecer un _bounty_ a la del e-mail para tener una respuesta canónica, que ahora no existe.

Comment: @fedorqui yo diría que en tu caso sería _e infant_ porque ya sea pronunciada en inglés o en español tal cual se lee, la siguiente palabra comienza comienza con un sonido _i_. En todo caso, una pregunta genérica que contemple cualquier posible caso (no sólo de palabras en inglés, sino en idiomas de más compleja pronunciación) podría estar bien.

Comment: @fedorqui [Ortografía, página 77](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=gGBtCrliHKzyWUDJ): lo que importa es el sonido de la palabra que sigue, no la grafía. Pone como ejemplos: _Iberia e Easyjet_, _Franco y Hitler_. _Easy_ se pronuncia como _isi_, pero _Hitler_ se pronuncia como _jítler_. Si no se está seguro del sonido, yo aplicaría lo que puse en mi respuesta a esta pregunta.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo fantástico. Mandé una pregunta para que quede allí como referencia.

Answer (score 2):

En estos casos en los que no se puede suponer cómo va a pronunciar la abreviatura el lector, queda en manos del que escribe el decidirlo. Si decide escribir `y HP` es que supone (y, en cierto modo, obliga) que el lector va a pronunciar las siglas. Si escribe `e HP`, supone que el lector va a pronunciar la versión completa sin abreviar.

Algo parecido pasa cuando la conjunción va seguida de una palabra extranjera de cuya pronunciación no se está seguro. Así, tendríamos `la aplicación funciona en iPhone y iPad` (suponemos que el lector va a decir *aipad*) o `la aplicación funciona en iPhone e iPad` (creemos que el lector va a decir *ipad*).

Answer (score 1):

Usa `e HP` aquí sin duda.

Razón: En ningún caso nadie va a decir `Hache pe` en lugar de `hipertensión pulmonar`.