# ¿"Toddler" en castellano?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término

Con frecuencia entro en la página de [Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/) y allí he cogido algo de vocabulario inglés sobre niños.

Allí, la "clasificación" por edades está definida como (fuente: [la lista de etiquetas](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/tags)): *newborn*: (0-3 meses), *infant* (3 meses - un año),  *toddler* (1-3 años), *pre-schooler* (3-5 años), *primary-schooler* (5-8 años), *middle-childhood* (8-11 años), *pre-teen* (11-13 años), *teen* (13-19 años).

Como no fui capaz de encontrar datos en la reconocida [Sociedad Americana de Pediatría](https://www.aap.org), miré en el CDC (Centers for Disease Control and Prevention) y en su sección de [Child Development](http://www.cdc.gov/ncbddd/childdevelopment/positiveparenting/index.html) mencionan:

- *infants* (0-1 año)
- *toddlers* (1-2 años)
- *toddlers* (2-3 años)
- *preschoolers* (3-5 años)
- *middle childhood* (6-8 años)
- *middle childhood* (9-11 años)
- *young teens* (12-14 años)
- *teenagers* (15-17 años)

A pesar de que no coincide totalmente, la idea es bastante parecida a la del sitio Parenting.

Todo esto no tiene mayor complicación a la hora de traducir al castellano lo que va a partir de los tres años: preescolares, niñez, adolescencia. Ahora bien, para *infants* y *toddlers* tengo serios problemas para encontrar traducciones adecuadas:

**¿Cómo decir *toddler* en castellano? ¿Es acaso un *bebé mayor*, tal y como [sugiere WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=toddler)?**

Lo de *bebé mayor* yo nunca lo he oído y de momento solo conozco el término bebé y luego ya niño, ambos bastante genéricos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como padre de un niño, yo simplemente he usado las palabras *bebé* y *niño*. La primera aproximadamente hasta que cumplió los dos años, y la siguiente de ahí en adelante. En todo caso, eso ya depende de cada uno, los bebés se desarrollan cada uno a su ritmo, y llega un momento en el que, simplemente, ya no "pega" llamarle bebé. Lo de *toddler* es para distinguir entre un bebé que ya da sus primeros pasos, que suele ser a partir de los 12 meses de edad (en algunos antes, en otros después), de los que aún no caminan solos.

Ahora ya como interesado por la lengua, en la Wikipedia tienes una interesante clasificación en la página sobre [pediatría](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pediatr%C3%ADa):

> Cronológicamente, la pediatría abarca desde el nacimiento hasta la adolescencia. Dentro de ella se distinguen varios periodos:
>
> - Recién nacido (0-6 días).
> - Neonato (7-29 días).
> - Lactante menor (1-12 meses).
> - Lactante mayor (1-2 años).
> - Preescolar (2-5 años).
> - Escolar (5-10 años).
> - Pre-adolescente (10-12 años).
> - Adolescente (12-18 años).

Así pues, la distinción que buscas sería entre **lactante menor** y **lactante mayor**. La bibliografía del artículo parece ser la *Historia de la pediatría española*, de Luis S. Granjel, publicado en 1965.

---

Sobre la traducción de *toddler*, el traductor de Google me ha propuesto una traducción de *toddle* que me ha gustado:

> [**pinito**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=T3oAKZN)
>
> Del dim. de *pino*.
>
> 1. m. Cada uno de los primeros pasos que da el niño o el convaleciente. U. m. en pl. *Está haciendo pinitos.*
> 2. m. pl. Primeros pasos que se dan en algún arte o ciencia.

Comment: ¡Interesante! Lo de lactante menor / mayor me resulta chocante, pues a partir de un año no suele haber demasiada lactancia. Pero bueno, si lo dice un experto yo qué voy a objetar. Así, _infant_ sería _lactante menor_ y _toddler_ _lactante mayor_. Magnífica respuesta, como siempre.

Comment: Esto puede ser en términos formales y hasta incluso, técnicos. En la vida cotidiana se dice `bebé` y `niño`. Yo trabajo en una tienda de artículos para bebés/niños, así que veo eso todos los días.

Comment: Cuando se habla de "lactante mayor" suele referirse a los que en su alimentación aún tienen un importante suplemento de leche, bien sea materna o preparados similares (en líquido o en papilla). Coincide con el segundo año de vida.

En cuanto a las "curiosidades" de la lactancia, en determinadas épocas eran normales periodos de lactancia (materna o con amas de cría) mucho más largos, no siendo infrecuente llegar incluso a los cinco o seis años. Por ejemplo, era frecuente en España durante la guerra civil y la posguerra con niños de cuatro o cinco años.

Answer (score 5):

I think it is going to be very hard to find a single word in Spanish which captures exactly the feel of toddler.

There is a verb *to toddle* which can be applied to anyone and which means to walk. It is however both informal and old-fashioned. The key feature of a toddler therefore must be that s/he walks. 
There is a particular way they walk which I think, although I am not an expert, is because their hip joints are not yet fully developed.

The verb sounds similar to *waddle* (to walk like a duck) or *totter* (to be in a state of uncertain equilibrium). Most of the translations given in the links proposed in comments and in @Carlos answer encode some of the literal meaning but not the full flavour.

Comment: Uhms, interesting. So it boilds down to finding a proper translation of _toddle_. [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=toddle) suggests _tambalear_ and _dar los primeros pasos_.

Comment: The only issue with _dar los primeros pasos_ is that the toddler may have walked for the first time some while ago.

Answer (score 2):

En un contexto más informal (y al margen de la categorización por edades), yo prefiero traducir *toddlers* por **retoños** o **críos**.

O como [indica proz.com](http://www.proz.com/?sp=gloss/term&id=829961):

> One translation of the English term toddler in Spanish is **chiquillo**, **crío**, **párvulo**.

Comment: ¿Pero no te parece que [_crío_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BH2HM3l) implica más que la franja de edad de uno a tres años? Lo mismo con [_retoño_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WI7hzZL). En ambos casos se indica "corta edad", que yo definiría en "menos de 8-10 años".

Answer (score 2):

Creo que una buena definición para "toddler" es **deambulador**. Al menos en algunas guarderias los denominan asi a los niños que ya no son bebes pero aún no están en sala de 3. Y se ejemplifica bastante con el inglés que indica que son "los primeros pasos": deambulador implica un desplazamiento aunque este pueda ser no del todo "perfecto" o dispar.

Comment: Great find.  http://psicopsi.com/deambulador-rasgos-principales-etapa: "El deambulador. La etapa deambulatoria abarca aproximadamente de los 15 meses a los dos años y medio."

Answer (score 1):

En psicología, se habla de "niño pequeño" cuando son menores de 6 años. Para mi "Toddler" sería "Niño pequeño".

Comment: Un niño de 4 o 5 años es un "niño pequeño", pero de acuerdo a ciertas definiciones es una _preschooler_ y no un _toddler_. Piensa en la pregunta de esta otra manera: cómo designar a un niño que tiene entre uno y tres años diferenciándolo de un bebé o de un niño de 4 años?