# correos & emails

Tags: ortografía, neologismos, email

En cierto lugar que no recuerdo en este instante, pude leer la frase (redundante a mi parecer) 'envien sus correos e *emails*'. Según entiendo el extranjerismo no es necesario, pero ya tiene un cierto arraigo. Sin embargo, en primer lugar creo que bastaría con mencionar 'envíen sus correos' incluyendo los 'físicos' y los 'electrónicos' y en segundo lugar... ¿la conjunción debe ser 'y' o 'e'?  La palabra la he oído como [Imeil] y como [Email] (no sé como escribirlo en AFI), por lo que queda la duda de la conjunción a utilizar (aunque si se va a usar la frase redundante sería mucho más correcto '*emails* y correos', evitando dolores de cabeza)

Comment: Creo que es mejor preguntar una sola cosa a la vez.  La segunda pregunta me parece más interesante.  Propongo que edites la pregunta, algo así: "En una frase como por ejemplo 'cuando recibo cartas e emails', ¿"e" es la conjunción correcta?"

Comment: Opino yo que si alguien hablase de cosas tecnológicas él conocería el concepto de "email"  .Te van a entender.  Pero, si quieres hablar eloquentemente, puedes decir "correo electrónico".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mira [¿Qué opción es correcta: “y e-mail” o “e e-mail”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12866/5481)

> debe usarse la forma «e» de la conjunción copulativa «y», pues se supone que casi todos los hispanohablantes leen eso como «imeil».

Sobre la primera parte de la pregunta, el DRAE apunta en la entrada de "[correo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AyfHjz9%7CAyjqP7U)" en su séptima acepción

> 7. m. correo electrónico.

Por lo que "correo" es sinónimo de "correo electrónico". Quizá podrías usar "carta" para referirte a "correos físicos" (tradicionales). Como curiosidad mira [¿Se usa “carta” para referirse a un “correo electrónico”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22374/5481)